# How can I correct the rule of updating the strategic vector in the Linear Reward Inaction algorithm (LRI)

Tags: java

Problem : I work on the Linear Reward Inaction algorithm (LRI),I have a problem in the rule of updating the strategic vector.Normally only one element of the vector must increase and the others must decrease except this is not my case. Here is the code I can not correct the error.

```
package LRI_algorithm;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Janvier_2017_stp {

    static double[][] MatResult = new double[150][150];
    static double[][] graph = new double[150][150];
    static double[][] graphProb = new double[150][150];
    static double[][] graphtemps = new double[150][150];

    static int tL = 142;
    static int tC = 142;


    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static double CalculEsperance (int[] path)
    {
        structuredonneesofficielles.stdproba.TraitementMatriceproba(graphProb, tL, tC, graphProb, tL, tC);
        structuredonneesofficielles.matrice_temps_VF.TraitementMatriceNouvelleTransition(graphtemps, tL, tC, graphtemps, tL, tC);    
        double costtemps = 0.0F;
        double costprob2 = 1.0F;
        double costprob1=1.0F;
        double cost=0.0F;

        double somme=0;
        double  i=cost;
        for (int j=0;j<path.length-1;j++)
        {

            costtemps=costtemps +graphtemps [ path[j]][ path[j+1]];   // somme le temps

            costprob2=costprob2 *(1-graphProb [path[j]][  path[j+1]]);//  produit (1-p)

        }

        costprob1=costprob2 *graphProb [ path[path.length-2]][ path[path.length-1]] * (1.0F/(1.0F- (graphProb [ path[path.length-2]][ path[path.length-1]])));//  produit p(1-p)

        cost=cost+ costprob2*costtemps+costprob1*costtemps;
        while (i <= path.length-1) { 
        somme = somme + i;
        i = i + 1;
        }
        return cost;
    }


    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static double Utilite (double esperance_max, double esperance, double  esperance_min) 
    {
        double U=0;
        U=Math.abs ((esperance_max-esperance)/(esperance_max- esperance_min));
        //U=Math.abs ((esperance_max-esperance));
        return U; 
    }
    public static void initializeMatrix(double[][] MatResult, double[][] MatResult1)
    {
        int nbL1 = 142;
        int nbC1 = 142;
        double[][] M_trans = new double[150][150];
        structuredonneesofficielles.stdproba.TraitementMatriceproba(MatResult,  tL, tC, graph, tL, tC);
        structuredonneesofficielles.transition_nouvelle.TraitementMatriceNouvelleTransition(M_trans, nbL1, nbC1,MatResult1, nbL1, nbC1);
    }
    public static int[] chemin_aleatoire(int depth, int start, double[][] MatResult, double[][] MatResult1,double [] esperance_param) {
                int nbL1 = 142;
                int nbC1 = 142;


                int state = start; // current state
                int[] save = new int[nbL1];
                int taille_save = 0;
                save[taille_save] = state;
                taille_save++;

                double  esperance_min=100;
                 double esperance_max=0;
                 double esperance=0;
                int nextState;

                int steps = 0;
                for (int tour=0; tour<50; tour++){
                while (state > 0 && steps < depth) {

                    steps++;

                double r = Math.random();

                    double sum = 0.0;
                    boolean stop = false;
                    int j =0;
                    //for (int j = 0; j < nbC1; j++) {

                    while ((j<nbC1) & (stop==false)) {
                        if (MatResult1[state][j] == 0) {
                        } else {
                            sum += MatResult1[state][j];

                            if ((r < sum)) {

                                save[taille_save] = j;

                                state = j;
                                //System.out.println(state+"|"+r);
                                taille_save++;
                                stop = true;
                            }
                        }
                        j++;
                    }

                            }

                // debut calcul du gain

                 esperance=  CalculEsperance(save);


                  esperance_param[1]= esperance;
                  esperance_min= esperance_param[2];
                  esperance_max= esperance_param[0];

                 if (esperance<esperance_min) 
                 {
                     esperance_min=esperance; 

                 }
                 if (esperance>esperance_max) 
                 {
                 esperance_max=esperance; 


                 }

                 esperance_param[0]=esperance_max;
                 esperance_param[2]= esperance_min;
                }
                 if (esperance<esperance_min) 
                 {
                     esperance_min=esperance; 

                 }
                 if (esperance>esperance_max) 
                 {
                 esperance_max=esperance; 


                 }
                double Utilite_save= Utilite(esperance_max,esperance,  esperance_min);
                 esperance_param[0]=esperance_max;
                 esperance_param[2]= esperance_min;
                 return save; 
    }
    public static int[] strategie_aleatoire(int depth, int start, double[][] MatResult, double[][] MatResult1,double [] esperance_param) {

        int nbL1 = 142;
        int nbC1 = 142;

        //int origine=98;
        int state = start; // current state

        int[] save = new int[nbL1];
        int taille_save = 0;
        save[taille_save] = state;
        taille_save++;

        double  esperance_min=100;
         double esperance_max=0;
         double esperance=0;
        int nextState;

        int steps = 0;

        while (state > 0 && steps < depth) {

            steps++;

        double r = Math.random();

            double sum = 0.0;
            boolean stop = false;
            int j =0;
            //for (int j = 0; j < nbC1; j++) {

            while ((j<nbC1) & (stop==false)) {
                if (MatResult1[state][j] == 0) {
                } else {
                    sum += MatResult1[state][j];

                    if ((r < sum)) {

                        save[taille_save] = j;

                        state = j;
                        //System.out.println(state+"|"+r);
                        taille_save++;
                        stop = true;
                    }
                }
                j++;
            };
                    }

        // debut calcul du gain

         esperance=  CalculEsperance(save);


          esperance_param[1]= esperance;
          esperance_min= esperance_param[2];
          esperance_max= esperance_param[0];

         if (esperance<esperance_min) 
         {
             esperance_min=esperance; 

         }
         if (esperance>esperance_max) 
         {
         esperance_max=esperance; 


         }

         esperance_param[0]=esperance_max;
         esperance_param[2]= esperance_min;




        double Utilite_save= Utilite(esperance_max,esperance,  esperance_min);
         esperance_param[0]=esperance_max;
         esperance_param[2]= esperance_min;
        // fin calcul du gain
        double b = 0.05;

        // parcourir save
        for (int p = 0; p < depth - 1; p++) {
            state = save[p];
            nextState = save[p + 1];
            double currentValueStateNextState = MatResult1[state][nextState];


            double[] nextValuesMatResult1 = new double[nbC1];

double sum = 0.0;
            // D'abord calculer les nouvelles valeurs
            for (int k = 0; k < nbC1; k++) {
                // D'abord on distribue les pénalités
                nextValuesMatResult1[k] = MatResult1[state][k];

                if ((k != nextState) & (nextValuesMatResult1[k] != 0)){
                    nextValuesMatResult1[k] = nextValuesMatResult1[k]
                            - ((nextValuesMatResult1[k] * b *Utilite_save)/ (1 - currentValueStateNextState));

                    if (nextValuesMatResult1[k] < 0) {
                        nextValuesMatResult1[k] = 0;

                    }

                } else {
                    if ((k == nextState) & (nextValuesMatResult1[nextState] != 0)) {
                        if ((nextValuesMatResult1[nextState] <1)) {
                            // Distribution des récompenses
                            nextValuesMatResult1[nextState] += b *Utilite_save;

                            if (nextValuesMatResult1[nextState] > 1) {
                                nextValuesMatResult1[nextState] = 1;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }


            }
// Normalize the sum, this case should happen only when the cumulated numerical error exceeds 1
// The following instruction are proposed to correct the computation of probabilities.

try{
String nomfichier = "Lri_Janvier_Dom.txt";


File nomFichier = new File(nomfichier);
PrintWriter fich;

fich = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nomfichier, true)));
for (int k = 0; k < nbC1; k++) {
    if(nextValuesMatResult1[k]!=0){
    //System.out.println (+k+"|"+nextValuesMatResult1[k]+"|");
    fich.print(+k+"|"+nextValuesMatResult1[k]+"|");

    }
    fich.println();
}
fich.flush();
fich.close();

}
catch (Exception e) {
}

            // Gérer le résidu au-dessus de 1 ou au-dessous de 0

            // Trier les valeurs de nextValuesMatResult1 et de MatResult1[state] et comparer leur ordre
            // si l'ordre change alors mettre à jour les valeur de MatResult1[state] avec ceux de nextValuesMatResult1

            // ordre est par choix, choisi comme ascendant du plus petit au plus grand.
            int[] ordreNextValuesMatResult1 = ordre(nextValuesMatResult1);
            //ordreNextValuesMatResult1
            int[] ordreMatResult1State = ordre(MatResult1[state]);

            boolean ordreEqual = true;
            for(int i=0; i < ordreNextValuesMatResult1.length;i++)
            {
                if(ordreNextValuesMatResult1[i] != ordreMatResult1State[i])
                {
                    ordreEqual = false;
                    break;
                }
            }



            // mettre à jour uniquement si l'ordre est different
            if(ordreEqual == false)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < nbC1; k++) {
                    MatResult1[state][k] = nextValuesMatResult1[k];
                    //System.out.println("please"+nextValuesMatResult1[k] );

                }
            }

            // fin de mise à jour

        }


            for (int k = 1; k < taille_save - 1; k++) {

                //System.out.println(+save[k] + "|" + MatResult1[save[k - 1]][save[k]]);
            //  printStream1.print(+save[k] + " ");
                // printStream2.print(MatResult1[save[k-1]][save[k]]+" " );

            }

        return save;

    }

    public static void printPath(int[] save) {
        double[][] M_trans = new double[150][150];
        double[][] MatResult1 = new double[150][150];

        int taille_save = save.length;
        int nbL1 = 142;
        int nbC1 = 142;
        structuredonneesofficielles.transition_nouvelle
        .TraitementMatriceNouvelleTransition(M_trans, nbL1, nbC1,
                MatResult1, nbL1, nbC1);
        System.out.println(save[0]);

        for (int k = 1; k < taille_save - 1; k++) {


            System.out.println(save[k]);


        }



    }

    public static int selectChild(int[] path, int depth) {
        int child;
        if (depth < path.length)
            child = path[depth];
        else
            child = -1; // -1 stand for the stop node
        return child;
    }
// test de convergence !!
    public static boolean comparePaths(int[] path1, int[] path2)
    {
        if(path1.length != path2.length) return false;
        for(int i=0; i < path1.length; i++)
        {
            if(path1[i] != path2[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Record starting time
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int startingPoints=98; startingPoints <99; startingPoints++) // tous les noeuds du graphe 
        {
            try{

                String nomfichier = "thierry_eval_prob_apres_convergence.txt";


                File nomFichier = new File(nomfichier);
                PrintWriter fich;

                fich = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nomfichier, true)));
            double[][] MatResult = new double[150][150];
            double[][] MatResult1 = new double[150][150];

            int depth =4; // la profondeur 
            int drop = 1; // la descente (je descends de drop pas)
            int maxLength =1; // nb tronçons

            int nbSimulations =5;

            float averageLearningSteps = 0;
            for (int simulationIndex = 0; simulationIndex < nbSimulations; simulationIndex++) {
                initializeMatrix(MatResult, MatResult1);
                float totalLearningSteps = 0;
                int currentNodeIndex = 0;
                int start = startingPoints; // position d'entrée dans l'orbite
                int[] foundPath = new int[maxLength];
                while ((start != -1) && (currentNodeIndex < maxLength))
                {
                    foundPath[currentNodeIndex] = start;
                    double[]esperance_param = new double[3];

                    int[] save = strategie_aleatoire(depth, start, MatResult, MatResult1,esperance_param);
                    //System.out.println("please");
                    totalLearningSteps++;
                    int[] save_aux;
                    int nbC1 = 142;

                    boolean converged = false;
                    //Le programme a été testé jusqu'ici
                    //Le programme a été testé jusqu'ici et fait 10 iteration pour voir s'il a convergé ou pas 
                    int numberMinimalIteration = 10;
                    int numberOfIteration = 0;

                            while((!converged))
                                        {
                                            save_aux = strategie_aleatoire(depth, start, MatResult, MatResult1,esperance_param);
                                            totalLearningSteps++;
                                            converged = comparePaths(save, save_aux);
                                            //System.out.println("****converged="+ converged);
                                            save = save_aux;
                    numberOfIteration++;

                    }   
                        for (int i = 0; i < nbC1; i++) {
                        if(MatResult1[start][i]!=0){

                    System.out.print(+i+"|"+MatResult1[start][i]+"|");
                    fich.print(i+"|"+MatResult1[start][i]+"|");
                    System.out.print("\n");

                        }


                                        }
                            System.out.println();


                    for (int i = currentNodeIndex + 1; i < currentNodeIndex + drop; i++) {
                        foundPath[i] = save[i - currentNodeIndex];

                    }

                    start = selectChild(save, drop);
                    currentNodeIndex += (drop);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < maxLength-1; i++) {

                }


                /* ces deux lignes nous donnes les itinéraires*/
            System.out.println("Simulation"+ simulationIndex );
                fich.println();
                fich.println("Simulation="+ simulationIndex );
                //System.out.println("****************The found path#"+ simulationIndex + " is :******************");

            //  printPath(foundPath);
                //System.out.println("*");
                //  System.out.println("The total learning steps neede for this path is : "+totalLearningSteps);
            //  averageLearningSteps += (float)(totalLearningSteps/nbSimulations);
    }
            //  System.out.println("_____________________The average learning step needed by simulation is : " + averageLearningSteps+ "_________________________");
        fich.println("*");  
            fich.flush();
                    fich.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                }       //System.out.println(startingPoints+","+averageLearningSteps);
        }

        // Get elapsed time
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Execution finished after " + elapsedTime + "ms");


    }


    // Renvoie un tableau representant les index des élements trié du plus petit au plus grand
    // à part d'un tableau double
    static int[] ordre(double[ ] a) {
        double[] a_aux = a.clone();

        int currentMinIndex = 0;        
        int[] indexOrdonnes = new int[a.length];

        int j=0;
        while(j < a.length)
        {
            double currentMin = 2;
            for(int i=0; i < a_aux.length; i++)
            {
                if(a_aux[i] < currentMin) {currentMinIndex = i; currentMin = a_aux[i];} 
            }

            indexOrdonnes[j] = currentMinIndex;
            a_aux[currentMinIndex] = 3;
            j++;
        }
        return indexOrdonnes;
    }

}
```

Comment: The problems encountered in this LRI code:
1) I can not add the sum in the calculation of the expectation (the first function)
2) I can not connect the calculation of Emin and Emax after 50 laps with the random strategy
Because the principle of this part is to make for 50 turns a random drawing of a path to calculate at each turn the expectation of the path and to determine after Emin and Emax.
After these 50 laps I have to randomly draw a route calculate his expectation and calculate Emin and Emax based on Emin and Emax determined after these 50 laps.
3) After I will have to update